# Find the index of a string in Javascript with help of first three characters

Tags: javascript, indexof

I have numerous tsv files each with header row. Now one column name in header row is `age`. In few files, column name is `age` while in other files it has EOL charcter such as `\r` `\n`.

Now how can i use `str.indexOf('age')` function so that i get index of age irrespective of column name age with EOL character such as `\n` , `\r` etc..

Foe eg:
tsv `file1`:

```
Name    Address   Age    Ph_Number
```

`file 2`:

```
Name    Address   Age/r
```

`file 3`:

```
Name    Address   Age\n
```

I am trying to find index of `age` column in each files header row.
However when i do-

```
header.indexOf('age')
```

it gives me result only in case of file1 because in other 2 files we have `age` as `age\r` and `age\n`..

My question is how should i find index of `age` irrespective of `\r` `\n` character along with `age` in header row.

i have following script now:

```
var headers = rows[0].split('\t');
    if (file.name === 'subjects.tsv'){
      for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var ageIdColumn = headers.indexOf("age");
        console.log(headers)
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. In the case of "name age address" You want to get 1? or 5?

Comment: Does `indexOf` not work? Being followed by `\n` or `\r` shouldn't affect the result of `indexOf`.

Comment: `indexOf()` returns the index of where the input string **starts** in the searched string. It will return the same number for `age` whether it is followed by other characters or not.

Comment: In addition to previous comments re `indexOf`, you could also pre-process the CSV files to modify line-endings with a separate program/script/automated process if you *really* need to normalize those for *other* reasons.

Comment: Are you really saying you have a `tsv` file and not a `csv` file? What is that?

Comment: @ScottMarcus tsv is a tab separated file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in the comments, `indexOf()` returns the starting position of the string. It doesn't matter what comes after it:

```js
var csvFile1 = 'column1,column2,column3,age,c1r1';
var csvFile2 = 'column1,column2,column3,age\r,c1r1';
var csvFile3 = 'column1,column2,column3,age\n,c1r1';

console.log(csvFile1.indexOf("age"));
console.log(csvFile2.indexOf("age"));
console.log(csvFile3.indexOf("age"));
```

If you specifically want to find the versions with the special characters,  just look for them explicitly:

```js
var csvFile4 = 'column1,age\r,column2,column3,age\n,c1r1';
console.log(csvFile4.indexOf("age\r"));
console.log(csvFile4.indexOf("age\n"));
```

**Lastly, it may be that you are confused as to what, exactly [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) is supposed to do. It is not supposed to tell you where all occurrences of a given string are. It stops looking after the first match.  To get all the locations, you'd need a loop similar to this:**

```js
var csvFile5 = 'column1,age\r,column2,age, column3,age\n,c1r1';

var results = []; // Found indexes will be stored here.
var pos = null;   // Stores the last index position where "age" was found

while (pos !== -1){
  // store the index where "age" is found 
  // If pos is not null, then we've already found age earlier and we 
  // need to start looking for the next occurence 3 characters after
  // where we found it last time. If pos is null, we haven't found it
  // yet and need to start from the beginning.
  pos = csvFile5.indexOf("age", pos != null ? pos + 3 : pos );
  pos !== -1 ? results.push(pos) : "";
}

// All the positions where "age" was in the string (irrespective of what follows it)
// are recorded in the array:
console.log(results);
```

Comment: Perfect.. 
But if i have headers in an array and want to find headers.indexOf('age'), then its not working..

Comment: i need to reframe my question. i didnt share complete problem. new to javascript.